# C++ program made with the lib sfml not running

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, game-engine, sfml

I'm trying to run an executable of a program made in c++ using sfml but nothing is happening, no error messages, just nothing

in the vscode powershell I put  `g++ -c main.cpp -IC:\Users\ferna\OneDrive\Documentos\Libraries\SFML-2.6.1\include` to compile the code into an object file and then `g++ main.o -o main -LC:\Users\ferna\OneDrive\Documentos\Libraries\SFML-2.6.1\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system` to take the object file created and generate an executable called main and then `./main` and that's where the unexpected happens, for me it was supposed to run the code and open the window with the green circle drawn, here is the code contained in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }
    std::cout << "RODOU";

    return 0;
}
```

I got these instructions including the code from the official SFML website  https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/start-linux.php

And also in the header where the sfml library is imported there is the following message "SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directorygcc" and I don't know why because I put the right directory path in the `c_cpp_properties.json` file.

Comment: The file `c_cpp_properties.json` is for IntelliSense, the editors highlithing and code-context behavior. It's the `tasks.json` file that is used for building. Please take some time to read [the Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs). Especially the relevant C++ section for your configuration.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and where in the tasks.json i put the path ?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? At a guess the sfml dlls are not on your path so the application fails to start

Comment: Yes and dont run

Comment: Did you go into properties and link everything? You need to tell the program where in which folder to find your needed files. I once had this issue where my SFML header didn't load, because I didn't direct everything. Also, what environment are you using? Visual Studio?